# How to get current html of a dom element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to retrive html of a dom element "abc".

```
<div id=abc>
<input id=xyz type=text value="2" />
</div>
<input  type=button value="2" onclick="show()"/>
<script>
document.getElementById("xyz").value=5;
function show(){
alert(document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

Lets say I modified the value of text box

1. by entering some value OR
2. by Javascript code

   document.getElementById("xyz").value=5;

but

```
alert(document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML);
```

always show me

```
 <input id=xyz type=text value="2" />
```

Why?
Can anyone tell me how I can get the latest html of the dom element "abc".?

Comment: Why would you need to see the updated value in the innerHTML?

Comment: I have several textbox and dropdown in a container where user can update the value. and I want to show / hide that container without rendering it again and again (without looping the json). Its a grid of many rows in it.

Comment: So why don't you show/hide with e.g. `document.getElementById("abc").style.display = 'none'` (or `inline` to show the input again)?

Comment: Oops, abc is a div, so use "block" to show it.

Comment: actually the same #container is shared by many of the javascript modules. so I cannot hide the container itself, one way is re-render the container's html/ or save the generated html somewhere and use it back.

Comment: I don't think I understand the context, but be aware that replacing the innerHTML you'll make you lose any event listener attached to the original elements.

Answer (score 2):

.value will not change the HTML.  If you want to do that, use .setAttrubute instead.  See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5EFXN/

```
document.getElementById("xyz").setAttribute('value','5');
```

Comment: but when user enters somevalue in text box?  then I need to update the  attribute? via onchange

Comment: I guess the real question is why do you want to change the html?